# How to set comma in array in php?

Tags: php, api

in my current project I have an array, which is e.g. "118" outputs. after the first number (at 118 the first 1) I would like to insert a comma.

I have already tried to use the "number_format ()" function to put a comma, but it always puts the comma at the end of the array.

My current code:

```
$api = "https://r6tab.com/api/player.php?p_id=";
$scenus = "3bb8d3bc-ab7a-45fb-8154-ed54897b2c4c";

$api_response_1 = file_get_contents($api.$scenus);

$scenus_kd = $api_response_1_decoded['kd'];


... <h4><?php echo number_format($scenus_kd, 2); ?></h4> ....
```

My current output:

```
118.00 but it should be spent like this 1.18
```

Comment: How does the original number look like? the one in `$scenus_kd`?

Comment: the original number without number_format() is 118

Comment: You may just have to use `number_format($scenus_kd/100, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number format doesn't insert a decimal point or comma. It rounds off the number. You used

```
number_format($scenus_kd,2)
```

That rounds off 118 to two decimal places, which is 118.00. If you want to turn 118 into 1.18, you need to divide it by 100:

```
number_format($scenus_kd/100,2)
```